lstm is not learning anything pytorch
I am trying to use lstm for binary classification of comments (comments are alredy pre processed and split). I created a model, but it is not learning anything.
In some cases I receive exactly the same accuracy no matter how many epoches I choose.
GitHub link: https://github.com/PavloChaika/ML_SET/blob/homework3/HW3/HA3%20-%20IMDB%20competition.ipynb
I tried different combinations of num_layers, hidden_size, learning_rate. I am using input_size because ithervise it works very slowly (even though I realize that I have only 1 input, i just try to train at least a little bit, and since I clasify comments my guess was that it should work) I tried using 1 input, but result was very similar

I figured out the reason. I simply didn't add pre processing to use embedings of my words intead of tokenized words
